# How to change the binding mode in runtime? Can I bind on it?

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I need a way to change the Binding mode from OneWay to TwoWay on runtime based on some values (mainly if the item is Visible I will make it TwoWay, otherwise OneWay, kindof master/slave controls).

Is this possible from xaml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is not Visible then why does it matter if it is TwoWay?

Comment: Because I'm binding on the diplayindex of one grid and when I drag one colum on the visible one after the change is done the other grid has a different displayindex on the same column and is reverting back the value. So I would like to set the displayindex binding to OneWay while the grid is not visible.

Comment: Have you got answer of that change the Binding mode from OneWay to TwoWay on runtime based on some values ?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible unless you do with code behind what the accepted answer says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by programmatically creating the binding, and recreating it when the condition changes.

Comment: Its not what I was asking for but anyway what I wanted was not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I made rebinding with following:

```
    private void OnTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // don't allow to update textbox from source if it has focus
        ChangeBindingMode(sender as TextBox, BindingMode.OneWayToSource);
    }

    private void OnTextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeBindingMode(sender as TextBox, BindingMode.TwoWay);
    }

    private void ChangeBindingMode(TextBox textbox, BindingMode mode)
    {
        if (textbox == null)
            return;
        Binding oldBinding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(textbox, TextBox.TextProperty);
        // It's not posible to change existing binding, but available to recreate it
        // oldBinding.Mode = mode;
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(textbox, TextBox.TextProperty);
        Binding newBinding = new Binding(oldBinding.Path.Path);
        newBinding.Mode = mode;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(textbox, TextBox.TextProperty, newBinding);
    }
```